# Horizontal slideshow like Firefox 4's tech demo

Tags: jquery

I want to create a content slider that works similarly to Firefox 4's showcase site:
http://demos.mozilla.org/

I'd like the inactive slider-items to actually be outside the browser, and to slide across to the centre when called. If I call an item that is 2 items back, I'd like to show the item in between scroll across and then off the screen, to reinforce the idea that they really are in a specific order.

Would anyone be willing to help me on my way with this?
Any help would be *greatly* appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two jQuery plugins to do something like this (and only one if you don't care about the hash being updated and being able to use the back/forward in the browser)

The first is the [jQuery cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).  Specifically, you want to look at the demo near the bottom of the [Intermediate demos 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html), this has the horizontal scrolling you want.  However, you can create custom animations to make it do easing/bouncing, etc.

For updating the hash, you want to use the [jQuery history plugin](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/).  This way when you click on an item, or go forward or back, you can update the hash accordingly so that users will be able to use the browser's back and forward buttons.

I really hope this helps!  I've used these two plugins before with good results doing a similar thing as you're wanting to do.

Comment: I've set up a jsfiddle demo if you feel like chiming in ;) http://jsfiddle.net/gBjnW/

How do I position previous and next items off-screen to the left and right? I think this plugin shows/hides rather than physically move their positions.

Comment: @thv20 Well it does both.  It shows the elements right before they slide in.  If you're doing a full-width slidey-thingie, this really should work perfectly for you.

Comment: @thv20 If you change the fiddle so that each of your img's are in div's and set all the div widths to 100%, you should see what I mean.

Comment: Wicked! Nearly got it! http://jsfiddle.net/gBjnW/4/ 

It's just skipping slides now, so if I go from 1 to 3, I'd like to see 2 scroll across. Any ideas there?

Comment: @thv20 I don't know that this plugin will do that per se, but I do know that you can set it up so that you only have back and forward buttons like on the original link you posted.  This will alleviate the need to skip slides.

Comment: Kinda want it to do that, hmm. This is a great start though, thanks for your help!